# ¿Funcion que controle proceso?

Tags: c++

Buenas, tengo problema deseo que esta función permita crear un evento nuevo y luego ingresar datos en el evento creado.
El problema es que si el usuario, primero digita opción 2, el programa empieza a pedir los datos.
Existe alguna función o como es el proceso para que mande un aviso de que primero debe crear el evento.

```
void evento(){
    int opcion;
    char d[10000];
    cout<<"BIENVENIDO";
    cout<<"1-Crear un evento";
    cout<<"2-Ingresar datos a evento nuevo";
    switch (opcion){
        case 1: cout<<"Usted va a crear un nuevo evento";
                cout<<"Por favor,indique el nombre del evento a crear";
                cin>>d;
                cout<<"Por favor, digite el valor de la boleta base (Sin comas ni puntos)";
                cin>>valorbase;
                cout<<"Evento creado con exito";
        case 2: cout<<"Va a ingresar los datos a su nuevo evento";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable booleana que esté inicializada a falso por defecto. Después, si entra primero en la opción 1 entonces cambiará a verdadero y si entra en la opción 2 pero sigue en falso mostrará el error y si no ejecutará el código correspondiente.

Quedaría algo así:

```
void evento(){
    int opcion;
    bool pasaSegundoPaso = false; //Nuevo
    char d[10000];
    cout<<"BIENVENIDO";
    cout<<"1-Crear un evento";
    cout<<"2-Ingresar datos a evento nuevo";
    switch (opcion){
        case 1: cout<<"Usted va a crear un nuevo evento";
                cout<<"Por favor,indique el nombre del evento a crear";
                cin>>d;
                cout<<"Por favor, digite el valor de la boleta base (Sin comas ni puntos)";
                cin>>valorbase;
                cout<<"Evento creado con exito";
                pasaSegundoPaso = true; //Le asignas el valor a true porque ya ha creado el evento
        case 2: 
               //Si no ha creado evento muestra mensaje. Si no, inserta los nuevos datos
               if(pasaSegundoPaso == false){ 
                   cout << "Debe crear el evento primero (Opción 1)";
               }else{
                   cout<<"Va a ingresar los datos a su nuevo evento";
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿La variable no debería ser estática?

Comment: @eferion La verdad que no controlo mucho de C++ y creo recordar que se inicializaba así la variable para usarla dentro del mismo método. Sin embargo, no lo he probado.

Comment: El problema es que la segunda vez que llames al método, si la variable no es estática, se volverá a inicializar su valor a `false`. Pero no es un problema exclusivo de esa variable que has añadido sino también de `d` y de alguna otra que no nos enseña.

Comment: @eferion Sí, pero entiendo que cada vez que crea un nuevo método quiere comprobar si esta comprobación esta hecha o no entrando a este método. Realmente sólo con esta función no podemos saber el resto del programa, yo pensaba que directamente ejecutaría el resto de código en el else del if.

Comment: Lo se, a lo que iba es que tu llamas a `evento` y `pasaSegundoPaso` se inicializa a false. Das de alta el evento y, como no hay bucles, el programa abandona la función. Llamas por segunda vez a `evento` y `pasaSegundoPaso` volverá a valer `false` pese a que has creado un evento en la primera llamada. No se si me estoy explicando

Comment: La idea inicial que yo tenia era la siguiente. Partamos del punto de que hay usuarios ociosos que ni viendo las opciones logran introducir la que se debe por lógica, hay entramos a trabajar los que programamos y queria que la funcion 1°- De la opcion de crear un evento. 2°-Permita ver el evento creado y luego permita ejecutar todo el resto del codigo.

Comment: @eferion Sí, pero entiendo que cada vez que entre a dicha función para crear un nuevo evento siempre tendrá que pasar por la opción 1. Si no crea el evento, que no introduzca sus datos, por eso siempre al iniciar la función lo inicializo a falso. Porque supongo que cada vez que entres en la función será para crear un nuevo evento.

Comment: ¿y el bucle para poder pasar dos veces por el switch?

Answer (score 1):

Tu función tal y como está escrita no tiene mucho sentido:

- Almacenas el nombre del evento en `d` (¿no podía llamarse mejor `nombreEvento`  o `evento`?)
- Dado que no hay bucles en la función se espera que el programa tenga que llamar varias veces a la función
- `d` no es estática, luego el valor introducido en la primera llamada no estará disponible en la segunda
- Tampoco habilitas ningún mecanismo para que el valor de dicha variable salga de la función o pueda pasarse desde fuera (ni return ni argumentos).
- ¿Qué es `valorBase`? Su declaracion la has omitido en el código.
- ¿Cómo funciona el ingreso de datos?
- Las cadenas de salida no tienen saltos de línea ¿Has probado el código en algún momento?
- Las opciones del `switch` no están separadas por un `break`. ¿Se te han olvidado?

Vamos por partes.

Si la función no se ha de llamar varias veces, entonce te falta un bucle en la función:

```
void evento()
{
  int opcion;
  do
  {
    cout << "BIENVENIDO\n"
         << "1-Crear un evento\n"
         << "2-Ingresar datos a evento nuevo\n"
         << "3-Salir\n";
    switch (opcion)
    {
      // ...
    }
  } while( opcion != 3 );
}
```

Si resulta que no, que se ha de llamar varias veces entonces lo lógico es que reciba vía argumentos los datos que necesita para funcionar. En cualquier caso (y esto es aplicable también al ejemplo anterior)  tendrías que indicar qué sucede si el usuario introduce un valor fuera del rango (1,2)

```
void evento(char* nombreEvento, /* ... */)
{
  int opcion;

  cout << "BIENVENIDO\n"
       << "1-Crear un evento\n"
       << "2-Ingresar datos a evento nuevo\n";

  switch (opcion)
  {
    // ...

    case default:
      /* ¿Qué hacer aquí? */
  }
}
```

Si resulta que la función ha de ser autocontenida y se va a llamar varias veces (no se me ocurre el motivo, pero viendo el estado del código tampoco se puede adivinar demasiado), entonces `d` debería ser estática para conservar su valor entre diferentes llamadas:

```
void NuevoEvento(char* evento, char* valor)
{
  cout << "Usted va a crear un nuevo evento\n"
       << "Por favor,indique el nombre del evento a crear";
  cin >> ptr;
  cout << "Por favor, digite el valor de la boleta base (Sin comas ni puntos)";
  cin >> valor;
  cout << "Evento creado con exito";
}

void evento(){
  int opcion;
  static char d[10000] = '\0';
  cout<<"BIENVENIDO";
  cout<<"1-Crear un evento";
  cout<<"2-Ingresar datos a evento nuevo";
  switch (opcion){
    case 1:
      NuevoEvento(d,valorBase);
      break; // ¿Seguro que no es necesario?

    case 2:
      if( *d == 0 )
        cout << "Primero debes crear el evento\n";
      else
        IntroducirDatosEvento(d);
      break;
  }
}
```

Me he tomado la molestia de sacar el código fuera de la función por simple legibilidad. Los `switch` ya pueden ser demasiado problemáticos como para ir tentando al diablo.